# Write to Excel ActiveX TextBox C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vbe

I have a C# program, and I want to write C# textbox string to excel ActiveX TextBox.

I can open a sample xlsx, write to cells, export as pdf... But cant write to textbox. I have found another question here, which could be the soultion

([Reach ActiveX or Form objects (textbox) from codebehind in an Excel document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351011/reach-activex-or-form-objects-textbox-from-codebehind-in-an-excel-document))

but I can't using "`Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;`", I have only `Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;`

Comment: Did you add the reference to `Microsoft Forms 2.0 object library`?

Comment: Yes, I added it.